# New SE mobile browser chat doesn't scroll on Windows Phone IE

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web

The page loads, but I can't scroll up or down.

Comment: Actually there may be one simple thing to try. Hold on tight.

Comment: Try now and let me know if it works, in which case the status-declined can become a status-completed after all.

Comment: @balpha yes it works now

Comment: Cool, thanks. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but so few people use our sites with Windows Phone that the amount can't justify spending time and work on supporting WP (unless it's a very easy and obvious fix).

In this case however, it was indeed an easy and fairly obvious fix: The scrollable area is a `<main>` element in the new mobile chat, and that element doesn't really exist in Internet Explorer. But it can be made to work just fine by explicitly making it `display: block`, which is what I did.

Comment: Does it make a difference that I have a very similar bug to this on an iPad? Haven't got around to reporting it yet, but essentially the page loads, scrolls a little, but won't scroll all the way up or down.

Comment: Yes, it should work on an iPad (although for what it's worth, the desktop version tends to work okay on tablets in my [Android] experience).

Comment: Aye, I use the desktop interface so I don't get that bug. Do you want a new bug report for what I've got?

Comment: Yes, please post one.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276061/new-mobile-chat-interfaces-only-partially-scrolls-on-ipad

Comment: Tapping on the chat window doesn't do anything except highlight what I selected. Is this a related issue or a separate one?