# New mobile chat interfaces only partially scrolls on iPad

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, ios

When I load chat on my iPad, it loads in the middle of the chat page. From there, I can scroll a little way in either direction, but I can't scroll all the way to the bottom or all the way to the top of the page.

This means I can't reach the input box at the bottom. I'm also unsure about whether there are supposed to be buttons at the top that I can see.

iOS 8 point something.