# None of the top bar buttons work in SE chat on Windows Phone IE

Tags: bug, chat, top-bar

Because tapping the buttons does nothing, I can't:

- see who's in a chat room
- switch between chat rooms
- access the options menu

I hope it's as easy a fix as was the case here:

[New SE mobile browser chat doesn't scroll on Windows Phone IE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276055/new-se-mobile-browser-chat-doesnt-scroll-on-windows-phone-ie)

Comment: 8.* is substantially different from 10, so you might want to include the OS version in your question, just for completeness.  I say, "just for completeness" because the phone's browser isn't officially supported by SE, so unless it *is* an easy fix, you're probably SOL.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows Phone 10. Please add more information.

Comment: This is affecting Windows Phone 8.1